# Since tvOS 10.2 the Apple TV displays a Airplay connection requires iOS 7.1 or later error

Tags: ios, tvos, airplay, tvos10

I have an Android app that can use AirPlay to play videos. Since my Apple TV 4 updated to tvOS 10.2 it has stopped working. I tried several other apps on Android and they all get the same error.

Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, basically you must force it to request a pin and do some other stuff. This sample explains it well https://github.com/funtax/AirPlayAuth

Disclaimer: not my code.

Answer (score 0):

tvOS 10.2 introduced a new verification requirement for Airplay streaming devices.

You can find more information about this in the following article:

http://cordcuttersnews.com/apple-tv-tvos-10-2-update-breaks-third-party-airplay/

Comment: Oh wow that is crazy, kills a ton of AirPlay apps. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario the AirPlay connection message shows every 30 seconds even though I am not trying to AirPlay to the Apple TV.
I have a hunch this may be related to the mDNS gateway on my Cisco 2504 Wireless LAN Controller.
The 2504 WLAN controller has mDNS support for apple Airplay but acts as a mDNS proxy/gateway between WLAN traffic encapsulated within the CAPWAP tunnel and LAN traffic.

But i have not confirmed this yet.

Comment: I had this issue while testing an android airplay app. Until I killed the app the message kept showing up and the apple tv stopped responding to the remote. Once I killed the app it took maybe 20 seconds before the remote started working again.